# WSO2 APIM Analytics: How to capture seconds in WSO2AM_STATS_DB

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have one requirement where the  Column Name '**Time**' in '**WSO2AM_STATS_DB**' should capture seconds also.
By default it captures only like **2018-11-18 15:04**. How it can capture the seconds also in Time column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well - the deployed siddhi streams are executing per-minute agregations. In theory - are you willing and able to update the analytics streams? Or - what is your purpose of the requirement - do you want to use the analtics server for storing all requests?

Comment: The purpose of the requirement is to see the number of hits happening for a particular user for an API in a complete day.
I am using API_REQUEST_SUMMARY table to get the details. In this table, we have Time Column which stores the value as yy-mm-dd hour:min. I want this value to be yy-mm-dd hour:min:sec

Comment: Also, to store the same in DB for further reference.